# Sign digital signature using Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, cryptojs

How to sign digital signature for zip document using Node.js ?

Crypto modules I find out under Node JS which helps for generating ,signing and verifying the digital signature. Is public and private both keys are mandatory ? Is that not achieved only using public key ?

Comment: Signing requires the private key, otherwise it would be pointless. By definition the public key is assumed to be public knowledge. If it was sufficient to sign anything, then anyone could create a signature, defeating the purpose of proving that the owner signed it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer so how can this code fully achieved ?